# ASP.NET "To Bottom" hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

On an aspx page I have following hyperlink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#Bottom" CssClass="ToBottom">To Bottom ↓</asp:HyperLink>
```

I would like to use it to navigate to the bottom of the page, more specificly, to an anchor with the name "Bottom":

```
<anchor name="Bottom" />
```

This doesn't work however... Any suggestions on how to make "To Bottom" and "To Upper" hyperlinks to quickly scroll through the page? Thanks.

**UPDATE:

A regular

```
<a href="#Bottom" class="ToBottom">To Bottom ↓</a>
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
<a href="#Bottom" class="ToBottom">To Bottom ↓</a>

<a name="Bottom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work (using href property):

```
<asp:HyperLink href="#Bottom" runat="server" CssClass="ToBottom">To Bottom</asp:HyperLink>
```

and building an anchor like:

```
<a name="Bottom"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but doesn't work unfortunately. An asp:Hyperlink doesn't have a href attribute

Comment: Create a single HTML control instead of creating an ASP.NET server control. This will improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a regular anchor elment for this, there's no use for a server control:

```
<a href="#Bottom" class="ToBottom">To Bottom</a>
```